# The command is disabled and cannot be executed

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa, racsignal, raccommand

So, when I trying to fetch some data, RACCommand return this error.

I have a picker for example and when user scroll it, app get data from server and show them, but if user scroll fast, (previous operation in progress) RACCommand get this error:

```
Error Domain=RACCommandErrorDomain Code=1 "The command is disabled and cannot be executed" UserInfo={RACUnderlyingCommandErrorKey=<RACCommand: 0x174280050>, NSLocalizedDescription=The command is disabled and cannot be executed}
```

I know, its related with some cancel mechanism, but I tried many examples and not working as well.

Its my piece of code:

```
    @weakify(self);
    [[[self.viewModel makeCommand] execute:nil]
     subscribeError:^(NSError *error) {
         @strongify(self);
         [self showAlertWithError:error];
     }];
```

and viewModel:

```
- (RACCommand*)makeCommand {
    if (!_makeCommand) {
        _makeCommand = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
            return [self getVehicleMake];
        }];
    }
    return _makeCommand;
}

- (RACSignal*)getVehicleMake {
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [[self.forumService getForumMakesWithYear:@([self.selectedYear integerValue])
                                         category:self.vehicleCategory]
         subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *result) {
             self.makes = result.first;
             [subscriber sendNext:self.makes];
         } error:^(NSError *error) {
             [subscriber sendError:error];
         } completed:^{
             [subscriber sendCompleted];
         }];

        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
        }];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`RACCommand` doesn't allow concurrent execution by default. When it's executing, it becomes disabled. If you try to execute again, it will send that error.

But you can test for that error—`RACCommand` has `RACCommandErrorDomain` and `RACCommandErrorNotEnabled` constants available.

```
@weakify(self);
[[[self.viewModel makeCommand] execute:nil]
 subscribeError:^(NSError *error) {
     @strongify(self);
     if ([error.domain isEqual:RACCommandErrorDomain] && error.code == RACCommandErrorNotEnabled) {
         return;
     } 
     [self showAlertWithError:error];
 }];
```